# D3 bar chart from geojson

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet

Has anyone worked on programmatic D3 bar charts inside div objects?

I'm developing a series of layers in a web map (leaflet) for a project and I'm struggling with this part. I understand the process of how to send a D3 object to a div which in turn is sent into a popup but I fail with the chart.

Some context: the data is in a geojson loaded with a link relation. My goal is to make a horizontal bar chart with a bar for each variable for the area clicked on ("LabMarPres","Educ","Earnings","Ind","Housing","AccToSer", "EcPerfInd").

I have found many examples for charts with data like this: "name", "value" but nothing that could help me understand how to make a chart for one area name with a bar for each values mentioned above.

The objective is to have a chart generated in the popup on a click.

I'm close, I can feel it. I have created a sample in a fiddle.
Thanks for any insights to set me in the right direction!

http://jsfiddle.net/kxamyoa5

Code:

```
var Sample = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 83,
            "Shape_Leng": 4.82699099667,
            "Shape_Area": 0.448245392274,
            "AreaName": "Area1",
            "LabMarPres": 0.47,
            "Educ": 0.56,
            "Earnings": 0.34,
            "Ind": 0.95,
            "Housing": 0.71,
            "AccToSer": 0.57,
            "EcPerfInd": 0.48
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -65.21807503043829,
                        47.80747318893657
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.12720779530349,
                        47.82663638466147
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.04717558318657,
                        47.83306401469258
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.03070994260975,
                        47.808330988384455
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.07368063185561,
                        47.78446441480094
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.32377354751117,
                        47.635343686761814
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.17873639716697,
                        47.47216492916817
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.29358005627455,
                        47.35396841221251
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.81588402532748,
                        47.23253275488281
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.21716123360403,
                        47.55064511288168
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.16380385856121,
                        47.966750274705475
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.73298300915849,
                        47.83039260553437
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.61017728505362,
                        47.65390380431717
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.21807503043829,
                        47.80747318893657
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 107,
            "Shape_Leng": 5.09713294978,
            "Shape_Area": 0.285706288115,
            "AreaName": "Area2",
            "LabMarPres": 0.39,
            "Educ": 0.56,
            "Earnings": 0.39,
            "Ind": 0.84,
            "Housing": 0.65,
            "AccToSer": 0.53,
            "EcPerfInd": 0.45
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [
                            -81.86826509136085,
                            49.58016077120266
                        ],
                        [
                            -81.86738708234793,
                            49.31949724400266
                        ],
                        [
                            -81.96549742666485,
                            49.058330969698545
                        ],
                        [
                            -82.27583456731139,
                            49.320275585649824
                        ],
                        [
                            -81.86826509136085,
                            49.58016077120266
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                        [
                            -82.47671511650935,
                            49.58123795846507
                        ],
                        [
                            -82.67823302333534,
                            49.45000960406003
                        ],
                        [
                            -83.07798109635047,
                            49.44957771453994
                        ],
                        [
                            -83.07752144116154,
                            49.580390592052254
                        ],
                        [
                            -82.47671511650935,
                            49.58123795846507
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 162,
            "Shape_Leng": 5.12799091297,
            "Shape_Area": 0.610219990564,
            "AreaName": "Area3",
            "LabMarPres": 0.61,
            "Educ": 0.61,
            "Earnings": 0.44,
            "Ind": 0.89,
            "Housing": 0.58,
            "AccToSer": 0.65,
            "EcPerfInd": 0.53
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -80.81235205370427,
                        48.79754602502908
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.4177094535284,
                        48.798039046864574
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.27503105943583,
                        48.62345072447141
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.27454603796923,
                        48.45013510824867
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.017245116369,
                        48.27609909729557
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.40460246423231,
                        48.27565976138891
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.42081344738267,
                        48.450625616479044
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.8131945574828,
                        48.450522225020734
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.81279867681747,
                        48.27715668383394
                    ],
                    [
                        -81.72681332037837,
                        48.27687831128509
                    ],
                    [
                        -81.72739491914018,
                        48.7106311025434
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.94382841594859,
                        48.71044270986323
                    ],
                    [
                        -80.81235205370427,
                        48.79754602502908
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 168,
            "Shape_Leng": 11.4173504124,
            "Shape_Area": 1.58006615738,
            "AreaName": "Area4",
            "LabMarPres": 0.49,
            "Educ": 0.54,
            "Earnings": 0.33,
            "Ind": 0.9,
            "Housing": 0.7,
            "AccToSer": 0.58,
            "EcPerfInd": 0.47
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -65.29358005627455,
                        47.35396841221251
                    ],
                    [
                        -64.88065039699819,
                        47.44903381755671
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.01747251744268,
                        47.27788412225448
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.26658863805517,
                        47.11635518624291
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.16514421283512,
                        47.03860454516371
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.14503370094451,
                        46.729783211825804
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.38608821330035,
                        46.61004800700999
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.58553702021726,
                        46.631193021640684
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.85170667362405,
                        46.336452850218905
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.16451905970678,
                        46.39648605738569
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.50983720911984,
                        46.294016035411744
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.62896209622374,
                        46.41230652882331
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.68829103710164,
                        46.84285340695919
                    ],
                    [
                        -67.0483476629143,
                        47.36288448253288
                    ],
                    [
                        -66.21716123360403,
                        47.55064511288168
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.81588402532748,
                        47.23253275488281
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.29358005627455,
                        47.35396841221251
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "OBJECTID": 231,
            "Shape_Leng": 7.79008441871,
            "Shape_Area": 0.18922060249,
            "AreaName": "Area5",
            "LabMarPres": 0.41,
            "Educ": 0.56,
            "Earnings": 0.37,
            "Ind": 0.9,
            "Housing": 0.7,
            "AccToSer": 0.53,
            "EcPerfInd": 0.46
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -64.88065039699819,
                        47.44903381755671
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.29358005627455,
                        47.35396841221251
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.17873639716697,
                        47.47216492916817
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.32377354751117,
                        47.635343686761814
                    ],
                    [
                        -65.07368063185561,
                        47.78446441480094
                    ],
                    [
                        -64.81585118768214,
                        47.80683922984662
                    ],
                    [
                        -64.67474884917999,
                        47.71399404289082
                    ],
                    [
                        -64.9034776061066,
                        47.557322269707015
                    ],
                    [
                        -64.88065039699819,
                        47.44903381755671
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([55, -95], 4);



    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, '+
            'Baselayer © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
    }).addTo(map);


    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: 'grey'
        };
    };

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#FFF',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
    };

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    };

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    };

    var onEachFeature_LMA = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });

        var div = $('<div class="popupGraph" style="width: 300px; height:200px;"><svg/></div>')[0];

        var popup = L.popup().setContent(div);
        layer.bindPopup(popup);

        var width = 500;
        var height = 300;

        var svg = d3.select(div)
        .select("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 150)
        .style("fill", "steelblue");

    }


    var geojson = L.geoJson(Sample, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature_LMA
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxamyoa5/27/).

The key to get a bar chart with your data is, that in your `onEachFeature` function, you have your data inside the `feature.properties`. With the following I prepare the data for the bar chart:

```
var values = feature.properties;
var data = [
  {name:"Educ", value:values["Educ"]},
  {name:"Earnings", value:values["Earnings"]},
  {name:"Ind", value:values["Ind"]},
  {name:"Housing", value:values["Housing"]},
  {name:"AccToSer", value:values["AccToSer"]},
  {name:"EcPerfInd", value:values["EcPerfInd"]}
];
```

This could be improved if there would be only properties that should be shown in the diagram. This way it is hardcoded for the names...

For a bar chart you have to append a rect per data element.

```
var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.value);})
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I add a `g` per element for conveniently positioning the `rect` and the `text` inside.

This example is based on [mike bostocks let's make a bar chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/).

Comment: jhinzmann, this is amazing! I will take the time to study your solution to fully understand it. From this, it should be easy to have the names show on the y axis and the values on the bars. The var data and var values is so interesting. I would never have thought about this. I need to study harder with javascript. I cant thank you enough!

Comment: I highly recommend working through the [tutorials page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) of the  D3 wiki in the order they are listed there. If your question is solved, please accept my answer ;)

Comment: I will definitely take the time to do that! I have accepted your answer. I cant upvote because I dont have enough reputation though. You have made my day, thank you again. I have bought some books too that I will read soon. This is fun!

Comment: I'm actually just sitting here and reading *Mastering D3.js*. gives quite a good overview on the topic. not so much in depth about d3 programming, but also about things like integration with backbone.js or packaging.

Comment: I got Getting started with D3 which I was going to go through this weekend. I will get Mastering too. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: jhinzmann, thanks to your guidance I was able to progress quite a bit. Using the same example, may I ask you how you would introduce a new series into the chart (different data). One set of bars is N11OL, etc. the other set would be N11NOL, etc. I am not quite sure how to modify this chart into a multiple series one. http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/p1pfhat8/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with another series. Something like a [grouped bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152)?
Please ask a new question for this topic.